# Change in ImageServer Behavior?

Tags: apex, custom-field, document

We have an app that manages images in Salesforce. Part of the functionality is generating Document records that are externally available, then saving the externally available link in a field on a record (which is useful for document merge apps like Conga, etc).

By default, the link to a Document looks something like this:

https://c.cs15.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015e0000000Mn1E&oid=00De0000005VzLP

Our app mods the link to be pod-agnostic like this:

https://login.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015e0000000Mn1E&oid=00De0000005VzLP

The "login" version of the link had been working fine, but we discovered this morning that it no longer works - only the "c.cs15" version works.

Modding the URLs to the "login" format was recommended to us to avoid any broken-link issues if a SF org moved to another pod.

Anyone else experiencing the same issue? Has anything recently changed with SF that would make the "login" format no longer work? Is there a new generic link option, or do we need to go back to the pod-specific format?

**UPDATE**

So, the plot thickens. Seems like it might be more pod or org-specific?

For comparison, both of these links work:

https://c.na24.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0151a000000AptiAAC&oid=00D1a000000XlckEAC

https://login.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0151a000000AptiAAC&oid=00D1a000000XlckEAC

So I guess the new question is why would it work for one org (or pod) but not another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://c.cs15.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015e0000000Mn1E&oid=00De0000005VzLP

I think cs15 is a sandbox, so it is reached through test.salesforce.com not login.salesforce.com

https://test.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015e0000000Mn1E&oid=00De0000005VzLP

Comment: Brilliant. After much staring at the problem, I didn't even recognize the sandbox vs production difference. Gold star.

Comment: Happy to help :-)